# Securely store credentials using AccountManager (Mono for Android)

Tags: android, security, xamarin.android, credentials, accountmanager

Could someone provide an example of the 'AccountManager' to securely store credentials locally on a device? (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

I only found examples for native (Java) Android and I need an example using Mono for Android.

Thanks in advance.